# Accessing individual records of GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-concat

I am using GROUP_CONCAT function to group records together separated by commas. I am using it like this

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(datetime, ' %H:%i ')) as time)
```

It's working great. I get the results like this

```
08:55 , 13:30 , 10:30 , 17:00 , 15:30 , 10:00
```

Now, what I want to do is, I want to select the individual elements of this grouped result, and place it inside a link, so that it passes a different value for a certain URL.

Something like

```
<a href="/timeaction/{value}">08:55</a>
<a href="/timeaction/{value}">13:30</a>
```

So, basically, I want each of the time to have a separate clickable link which goes to a certain URL, with it's value. It's value will be the time itself. Preferably I would want to use a foreach loop, something like this

```
foreach($time as $times){
<a href="/timeaction/$times">$times</a>
}
```

How can I do this? I am using Laravel as a templating engine.

Comment: Convert your string to an array and you'll be able to loop through with a `foreach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the string to an array you can loop through them:

```
$timeStr = '08:55 , 13:30 , 10:30 , 17:00 , 15:30 , 10:00';
$times = explode(',', $timeStr); // converts string to array
foreach($times as $time) {
    $cleanTime = trim($time); // cleanup the  spaces
    echo "<a href='/timeaction/$cleanTime'>$cleanTime</a>";
}
```

This will return:

```
<a href='/timeaction/08:55'>08:55</a>
<a href='/timeaction/13:30'>13:30</a>
<a href='/timeaction/10:30'>10:30</a>
<a href='/timeaction/17:00'>17:00</a>
<a href='/timeaction/15:30'>15:30</a>
<a href='/timeaction/10:00'>10:00</a>
```

Comment: Why are you using the trim function?

Comment: Because there are spaces (from the original string) around the times after you perform the explode.

Comment: You can also use `explode(' , ', $timeStr);`, and without `trim()`